# how to call an ActiveX method in QT?

Tags: qt

I know  class id of the ActiveX.then how to call a function defined in the ActiveX?
For example, int f(string *).

Answer (score 0):

QT has very good documentation and examples on its COM/ActiveX integration:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/examples-activeqt.html